# plantUML plug-in for VSC on Mac returns 403 when Option-D render is selected

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, plantuml

This just started happening...when I choose to render my plantUML diagram in VSC I get this...it used to work, just recently started happening.  I should mention this is a work Mac, and they often go about hacking stuff out as "security threats" with reckless abandon. Could that be what this is?  It's acting like I don't have authorization on plantUML to use their engine to render.

```
`Error: 403 Forbidden

GET https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/0/...
at ClientRequest.closeCallback (/Users/mdaugherty/.vscode/extensions/jebbs.plantuml-2.17.5/out/src/plantuml/renders/httpWrapper.js:78:27)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:405:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:538:35)
at node:net:687:12
at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7)`
```

I have rebooted, loaded everything.  The diagram renders on Confluence Cloud plantUML macro.

Comment: You could try generating a URL for the diagram (right click menu) and see if you can open it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, PlantUML seems to added a restriction of about 14000 character limit on their API.

Try with smaller files, it worked for me but it is still unfortunalty not good enough because the UML must be connected.

Comment: Did you have a look at the setting `PLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE` see e.g. https://forum.plantuml.net/10465/how-plantuml_limit_size-when-running-intellij-idea-plugin (which might give some pointers).